# Prevent Photoshop CC2015 from closing short brush strokes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2015, wacom

How to prevent Photoshop CC2015 (Windows 10) from closing short brush strokes? See the gif below:

[image]

In the case of smaller strokes photoshop closes the stroke atomatically. I am using a Wacom Intuos tablet. This behaviour doesn't happen when the strokes are created with mouse instead of a pen.

**Update 1:**

I was trying to give you a gif with the cursor included and I have stumbled upon this odd behavior: the cursor moves along on my screen even for the shorter strokes, however, it doesn't move on the gif. This could mean that for the smaller strokes there are two active cursors one of which stays in a fixed position till a certain stroke length threshold is reached. See the gif below:

[image]

**Update 2:**
This odd behavior is due to the tablet, since on a zoomed canvas the same behavior is present:

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @Ryan "How to prevent Photoshop CC2015 from closing *short brush strokes*?" The brush tool.

Comment: This happens with Pen tools but never heard of anything like this with Brush tool so if you're correct on the tool then sorry but I've got no idea

Comment: @Ryan See the update, some weird stuff is happening.

Comment: Hmm, not sure anyone here will help. This might be a "Clear preferences or contact tech support." The only thing I can think of with your update is perhaps your Mouse and Pen are interfering with each other. I've only had that happen with Mouse though if I leave the Wacom Stylus resting on the tablet, your issue is the opposite way if I'm understanding right so doubt this is it.

Comment: @Ryan Disabling my mouse doesn't help though, I am suspecting some sort of a resolution issue within the tablet's hardware. I would like to confirm if anyone with Wacom Intuos tablet is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this in CC2017 as well. Windows 10 with an Intuos Pen and Touch Small.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same behavior appear as well. Photoshop closes small U-like strokes when using the brush with a tablet. I do not have the same behavior if I enable pressure sensitivity, however. Perhaps this is a fix? As far as I know, you can disable the effects of pressure even with the setting turned on.

Hope that helps someone!